# How do you list all warning filters in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, warnings

I just spent the day trying to remove this warning from my output:

```
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/dev/null' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

I just finished a binary search of about 100k lines of code to try to figure this out. I still haven't found what's leaving `/dev/null` open, but I did find that some of our code says:

```
warnings.simplefilter("always")
```

Removing that removes the warning. Hooray! I plan to remove that bit of code, but I'm curious of two things:

1. Could I have avoided doing a binary search for this somehow? Enabling `TRACEMALLOC=1` was entirely ineffective (maybe because this is in third-party code we import?)
2. Once I remove this, is there a way to list all of the warning filters that are applied at a particular point in the code? Seems like an important thing to be able to analyze, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `grep` for `import warnings` (or the `from` variant).
It's not as though that's a common thing to import.

After executing someone else's code,
you can always

```
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

to disable what they enabled,
even without reviewing their source code.

---

You can view current filters in this way:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(warnings.filters)
[('default', None, <class 'DeprecationWarning'>, '__main__', 0),
 ('ignore', None, <class 'DeprecationWarning'>, None, 0),
 ('ignore', None, <class 'PendingDeprecationWarning'>, None, 0),
 ('ignore', None, <class 'ImportWarning'>, None, 0),
 ('ignore', None, <class 'ResourceWarning'>, None, 0)]
```

Comment: Was there a better way to find the code generating that warning? Binary search was kind of terrible.